# Creating a keyboard command with AHK, no *else* statement

Tags: autohotkey

I want to have the same shortcut for tabs in my pdf reader as in my browser. With AHK I wrote:

```
^PgUp::
IfWinActive Foxit Reader
    Send {Ctrl down}
    Send {Shift down}
    Send Tab    
else
return
```

But it complained that I did not had anything after my *else*. So I tried

```
^PgUp::
IfWinActive Foxit Reader
    Send {Ctrl down}
    Send {Shift down}
    Send Tab    
else
    MsgBox nada
return
```

Still did not work. How do I solve this?

---

Question 2

What's wrong with this code?

```
!^#n::
WinActivate Notepad++
Send {Ctrl down}
Send {Shift down}
Send n
return
```

Comment: Instead of Send {Ctrl down}
Send {Shift down}
Send n(its wrong anyways read help file on Send command) use Send ^+n

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use any `else`, and surround your commands with curly braces:

```
^PgUp::
IfWinActive Foxit Reader
{
    Send {Ctrl down}
    Send {Shift down}
    Send Tab    
}
return
```